# Minimize the entries in Postgres database

Tags: json, database, postgresql, nosql

I want to create an application which makes the process of obtaining clearance from different department easier. In this, my application has to be optimized and less sized. [Employee and Department List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxo8P.jpg)

If there are 100 employees and 10 departments, filling up rows and columns would take 1000 entries to be made in the Postgres. Is there any way to minimize the entries to be made in database. I read about JSON where the same information can be written in single line and stored in DB. Though it reduces the size of the entries to be made, am afraid whether it will be easier to search through the entries made? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *normalize* your schema, and instead have two separate tables for employees and departments.  Then, create a third *junction* table, which stores the relationship between employees and the departments to which they belong.  Something like this:

```
Employees (id, name, age)
Departments (id, name, category)
Employee_Department (emp_id, dept_id)
    -- emp_id refers to Employees (id) and dept_id refers to Departments (id)
```

Using your example of 100 employees each belonging to 10 departments, now the `Employees` table would only have 100 records, and the `Departments` table 10 records.  The junction table `Employee_Department` would have some multiple number of records, perhaps as high as 1000.  But, the data being stored in each record of the junction table is minimal, and only involves two ID values, which is not a big storage burden.  The metadata for employees and departments only is stored once, in each of the respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of applying best practices of relational database modelling, the answer from @Tim Biegeleisen is the way to go. 
If you think of nosql (as one of question tags implies) and want to use Postgres, you might make use of JSON data type of Postgres, refer to [Postgres JSON datatype documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-json.html). 
Postgres provides also indexing on JSON fields, so even searches should be no issue.